How to test asynchronous function using plenary.nvim?
I'm writing a plugin for lualine.nvim for GNU gettext .po files to show the result of msgfmt --statistics similar to vim-airline does.
I have written the function to fetch the statistics for the current .po file in lua/po/statistics.lua:
local M = {}

---@param filename string The name of the po file.
---@param statistics_lang string The language of the statistics text.
---@param callback function The callback function against the statistics text.
local function fetch(filename, statistics_lang, callback)
    vim.system(
        { "msgfmt", "--statistics", "--output-file=/dev/null", filename },
        { env = { LANG = statistics_lang }, text = true },
        function(obj)
            if obj.code ~= 0 then
                return
            end

            local s, _ = string.gsub(obj.stderr, "^%s*(.-)%s*$", "%1")

            callback(s)
        end
    )
end

M.fetch = fetch

return M


And the custom component in lua/lualine/components/po.lua:
local statistics = require("po.statistics")

local M = require("lualine.component"):extend()
local statusline = ""

function M:init(options)
    M.super.init(self, options)
end

function M:update_status()
    local filepath = vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)
    if filepath == "" then
        return ""
    end

    local extension = vim.fn.fnamemodify(filepath, ":e")

    if extension ~= "po" then
        return ""
    end

    statistics.fetch(filepath, vim.env.LANG, function(statistics_text)
        statusline = statistics_text
    end)

    return statusline
end

return M

Everything works as expected so far, but I'm facing difficulties writing a test for the fetch function using plenary.nvim.
Here's what I have in my test:
local statistics = require("po.statistics")

describe("fetch", function()
    it("fetches the statistics text of the given po file content.", function()
        statistics.fetch("test/statistics/spec.po", "C", function(statistics_text)
            assert.equals("foo bar baz", statistics_text)
        end)
    end)
end)

The issue is that this test always passes, regardless of the content of test/statistics/spec.po because fetch is asynchronous, and the it block completes before the callback function is executed. The use of vim.system(...):wait() doesn't help since a callback is provided.
I found async.util.block_on and async.tests, but I couldn't figure out how to use them.
Since lualine.nvim calls M:update_status frequently, I don't want fetch to be synchronous. How do I modify the test to make it work?
I'm using Neovim v0.10.1.

Make fetch async by wrapping vim.system with async.wrap.
---@param filename string The name of the po file.
---@param statistics_lang string The language of the statistics text.
---@return string|nil The statistics text of the given po file, or nil on an error.
local function fetch(filename, statistics_lang)
    local async_system = async.wrap(vim.system, 3)

    local obj = async_system(
        { "msgfmt", "--statistics", "--output-file=/dev/null", filename },
        { env = { LANG = statistics_lang }, text = true }
    )

    if obj.code ~= 0 then
        return
    end

    local s, _ = string.gsub(obj.stderr, "^%s*(.-)%s*$", "%1")

    return s
end

And then use plenary.async.tests.
local statistics = require("po.statistics")
local async = require("plenary.async")

async.tests.describe("fetch", function()
    async.tests.it("fetches the statistics text of the given po file content.", function()
        local actual = statistics.fetch("test/statistics/spec.po", "C")

        assert.equals("foo bar baz", actual)
    end)
end)

It will make the test fail, which means it works. Changing "foo bar baz" to "0 translated messages." will make it pass.
Make sure to use async.void in M:update_status.
function M:update_status()
    local filepath = vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)
    if filepath == "" then
        return ""
    end

    local extension = vim.fn.fnamemodify(filepath, ":e")

    if extension ~= "po" then
        return ""
    end

    async.void(function()
        local s = statistics.fetch(filepath, vim.env.LANG)

        if s ~= nil then
            statusline = s
        end
    end)()

    return statusline
end

